# chrome: border-radius on image with padding and background

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I would like to create hover effect with gradient circle. This code work in firefox and used to work in chrome before. Now chrome doesn't apply border-radius on padded image. Please, is it possible to make it work in chrome again? Thanks for help.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  transition: padding .4s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:hover>img {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #d31249, #F60);
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">
 <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/important-person_318-10744.jpg" alt="">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the effect on the `a` element instead of the `img`. I have also added the fadeout effect so the gradient is also visible on mouseout

```css
a.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  transition: padding .4s, background-size 0s 0.4s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #d31249, #F60);
  background-size: 0 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

a.wrap:hover {
  padding: 15px;
  transition: padding .4s, background 0s;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="wrap">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/important-person_318-10744.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```